# How to add timestamp in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have a data which have the difference between the start and end time of an event. Now I want to add the difference. the problem is the difference time is in format

```
difference_time
_______________
00:10:00
00:30:12
01:09:09
00:09:03
01:09:30
01:09:03
00:09:08
01:00:09
09:00:01
```

But if I do `sum(df$difference_time)` it throws the error that invalid type of arguement.

I want the result to be something like below format:

51975 seconds.
Any help is appreciated

**UPDATE:**

I tried `period_to_seconds(hms(df$difference_time))` and it works fine

Comment: Does this work: `sum(as.difftime(df$difference_time, format = "%H:%M:%S"))`?

Comment: are ok to convert it to numbers and add, it will be simpler, but even this format can be added

Comment: @emilliman5 No it gave NA in all the results

Comment: @ Pradi KL What do u mean by convert it to numbers and add.It is ok  if the end results are in seconds/minutes

Comment: period_to_seconds(hms(df$difference_time)) works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
period_to_seconds(hms(df$difference_time))
```

did the trick.