# Combine timestamp to total time in lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

I have the following dataframe:

```
  VideoDuration
1      00:02:17
2      00:02:17
3      00:01:47
4      00:02:37
5      00:02:41
6      00:04:00
```

I want to combine the timestamp in the column (VideoDuration) to recieve a single value.

For example, for the above rows: 14m59s

Any clue how I can do this in lubridate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44242291/5325862 seems like it should get you started

Answer (score 2):

**1.`lubridate`**

Use `hms` to convert the original string to `period` > use `period_to_seconds` to convert to seconds > add the second values > use `seconds_to_period` to convert back to `period`

```
library(lubridate)
seconds_to_period(sum(period_to_seconds(hms(d$VideoDuration))))
#[1] "15M 39S"
```

**2. `chron`**

```
library(chron)
sum(times(d$VideoDuration))
#[1] 00:15:39
```

**DATA**

```
d = structure(list(VideoDuration = c("00:02:17", "00:02:17", "00:01:47", 
                                     "00:02:37", "00:02:41", "00:04:00")),
              class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```